# Error When Combining Scripts using the ToolKitScriptManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web application in which i am using the ToolkitScriptManager as below:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release"
    LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" runat="server" CombineScripts="false">
 <CompositeScript>
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/Validators.js" />
</Scripts>
 </CompositeScript>
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

This works fine but from a performance standpoint this is not good as the pages are making a lot of requests to the webresources.axd and scriptresource.axd files. When I changed the CombineScripts property to true my ASP.NET AJAX control extenders are no longer working. What is the reason for this weired behavior and is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same problem, both this setting (CombineScripts) and the compression web.config compression generate sys is undefined errors with no specific pattern (some pages work, some errors only on IE)

> ```
> <system.web.extensions>
>     <scripting>
>         <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/>
>     </scripting>
> </system.web.extensions>
> ```

we will address this issue in a future sprint task (for performance considerations), till then looking for the same answer...